# ruby monkey patching on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to implement monkey patching while an object is being instantiated?

When I call:

```
a = Foo.new
```

Prior to the instance being instantiated, I would like to extend the Foo class based on information which I will read from a data store. As such, each time I call `Foo.new`, the extension(s) that will be added to that instance of the class would change dynamically.

Comment: It doesn’t matter when you do it; it’s just code. But you’re describing instance modification, not class modification, and there’s probably a better way to implement it.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you may have tried.
see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

I haven't try it yet, just wanted to know if it is possible. I'll make an attempt and I'll send some feedback.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at what ActiveRecord does with the models. It loads the schema before finalizing the creation of the object, something done inside the `class Base` block.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".
 Rather than ask before you've tried something, the SO way is to research, research, research, try, try, try a lot more, and THEN ask. SO isn't a tutorial site, it's to help fix problems with your code.

Comment: What you're describing isn't monkey patching,  IMO.

Comment: @jvillian:
I also agree but, I didn't know any other name to call it which described what I want to do. From the other answers, I can see now that I just trying to extend the class/instance at runtime...

Comment: @the Tin Man:
Thank you for correcting the text. I think it is valid for me to ask for hints that could assist me on how to Approach an issue. Anyway, I do appreciate this forum and I'll do my best to follow the rules on how to write a question...

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: Adding methods to an instance is possible.

Answer: Adding methods to an instance is not possible. Instances in Ruby don't have methods. But each instance can have a singleton class, where one can add methods, which will then be only available on the single instance that this singleton class is made for.

```
class Foo
end

foo = Foo.new

def foo.bark
  puts "Woof"
end
foo.bark

class << foo
  def chew
    puts "Crunch"
  end
end
foo.chew

foo.define_singleton_method(:mark) do
  puts "Widdle"
end
foo.mark
```

are just some of the ways to define a singleton method for an object.

```
module Happy
  def cheer
    puts "Wag"
  end
end
foo.extend(Happy)
foo.cheer
```

This takes another approach, it will insert the module between the singleton class and the real class in the inheritance chain. This way, too, the module is available to the instance, but not on the whole class.

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind also. I will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can!

```
method_name_only_known_at_runtime = 'hello'
string_only_known_at_runtime = 'Hello World!'

test = Object.new
test.define_singleton_method(method_name_only_known_at_runtime) do
  puts(string_only_known_at_runtime)
end

test.hello
#> Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

> Prior to the instance being instantiated, I would like to extend

Given a class `Foo` which does something within its `initialize` method:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    self.name = name
  end
end
```

And a module `FooExtension` which wants to alter that behavior:

```
module FooExtension
  def name=(value)
    @name = value.reverse.upcase
  end
end
```

You could patch it via [`prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Module.html#method-i-prepend):

```
module FooPatcher
  def initialize(*)
    extend(FooExtension) if $do_extend # replace with actual logic
    super
  end
end

Foo.prepend(FooPatcher)
```

Or you could `extend` even before calling `initialize` by providing your own [`new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Class.html#method-i-new) class method:

```
class Foo
  def self.new(*args)
    obj = allocate
    obj.extend(FooExtension) if $do_extend # replace with actual logic
    obj.send(:initialize, *args)
    obj
  end
end
```

Both variants produce the same result:

```
$do_extend = false

Foo.new('hello')
#=> #<Foo:0x00007ff66582b640 @name="hello">

$do_extend = true

Foo.new('hello')
#=> #<Foo:0x00007ff66582b280 @name="OLLEH">
```